# libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::length_error: vector

Tags: c++, xcode, vector

I am really new in C++. I know it may be due to wrong memory allocation, but I have tried to run lines indicating errors solely and found nothing wrong...

Function with Error part(t is 1211200*7 array):

```
vector<double>tmp;
vector<size_t>tmpsort;
long ctmp=1000000,c=570404,l=1211200,indt=0;
double** m = new double*[ctmp];
for(int i = 0; i < ctmp; ++i)
    m[i] = new double[7];
    double** mt = new double*[c];
    for(int i = 0; i < c; ++i)
        mt[i] = new double[7];
for (int i=0; i<l; i++) {
    if (t[i][0]!=0&&t[i][1]!=0) {
        mt[indt][0]=t[i][0];
        mt[indt][1]=t[i][1];
        mt[indt][2]=t[i][2];
        mt[indt][3]=t[i][3];
        mt[indt][4]=t[i][4];
        mt[indt][5]=t[i][5];
        mt[indt][6]=t[i][6];
        indt++;
    }
}
for (int i=0; i<c; i++) {
    tmp.push_back(pow(pow(distanceEarth(mt[i][1], mt[i][0], d[1], d[0]),2)+pow(mt[i][2]-d[2],2),0.5));
}
    tmpsort.assign(ordered(tmp).begin(), ordered(tmp).end());//signal SIGABRT
    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
        m[i][0]=mt[tmpsort[i]][0];
        m[i][1]=mt[tmpsort[i]][1];
        m[i][2]=mt[tmpsort[i]][2];
        m[i][3]=mt[tmpsort[i]][3];
        m[i][4]=mt[tmpsort[i]][4];
        m[i][5]=mt[tmpsort[i]][5];
        m[i][6]=mt[tmpsort[i]][6];
    }
    c=1000;
```

For ordered(from [c++ sort keeping track of indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580982/c-sort-keeping-track-of-indices)):

```
template <typename T>
vector<size_t> ordered(vector<T> const& values) {
vector<size_t> indices(values.size());
iota(begin(indices), end(indices), static_cast<size_t>(0));

sort(begin(indices), end(indices),[&](size_t a, size_t b) { return values[a] < values[b];});
return indices;
}
```

For distanceEarth(a function which can return the distance between two points):

```
double deg2rad(double deg) {
return (deg * M_PI / 180);}
double rad2deg(double rad) {
return (rad * 180 / M_PI);}
double distanceEarth(double lat1d, double lon1d, double lat2d, double lon2d) {
double lat1r, lon1r, lat2r, lon2r, u, v;
lat1r = deg2rad(lat1d);
lon1r = deg2rad(lon1d);
lat2r = deg2rad(lat2d);
lon2r = deg2rad(lon2d);
u = sin((lat2r - lat1r)/2);
v = sin((lon2r - lon1r)/2);
return 2.0 * earthRadiusKm * asin(sqrt(u * u + cos(lat1r) * cos(lat2r) * v * v));}
```

The terminal shows the error message as title. Can anyone suggest me what to check next? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem here:

```
tmpsort.assign(ordered(tmp).begin(), ordered(tmp).end());//signal SIGABRT
```

The function `ordered` returns by value. This means that `begin()` and `end()` is called for different temporary vectors.

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask how I can assign ordered(tmp) to tmpsort? The function is not main function so I cannot use "=" here...

Comment: They both seem to be `vector<size_t>`, so plain assignment should work.

Comment: Xcode suggests that "No viable overloaded '='". I use push_back instead and it successfully works.

Comment: Updated: still get crashed after changing to the following lines:
    for (auto i:ordered(tmp)) {
            tmpsort.push_back(i);//signal SIGABRT
    }

Comment: Updated:The above error happened just only with pushing back the first element from i. Somehow initialising tmpsort with range solves it.

Comment: Update:Problem seems to be solved if declaring vector with size in initialisation