# expected expression before '['

Tags: c++, g++

I am a newbie in programming. Recently I try to use the sorting function from [c++ sort keeping track of indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580982/c-sort-keeping-track-of-indices)

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<size_t> ordered(std::vector<T> const& values) {
std::vector<size_t> indices(values.size());
std::iota(begin(indices), end(indices), static_cast<size_t>(0));

std::sort(
    begin(indices), end(indices),
    [&](size_t a, size_t b) { return values[a] < values[b]; }
);
return indices;
}
```

In Xcode, it is successfully compiled without any warnings. While in g++, it shows the following error message:

```
error: expected expression
          [&](size_t a, size_t b) { return values[a] < values[b];}
          ^
```

What does it imply? Thanks!

Comment: How are you invoking g++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`begin` and `end` reside in the `std` namespace.  You need to qualify them:

```
std::sort(
    std::begin(indices), std::end(indices),
    [&](size_t a, size_t b) { return values[a] < values[b]; }
);
```

Also [lambdas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) are a C++11 feature so you need to compile with `-std=c++11` to use them.